# Github Pages Not Showing Data With gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I am trying to link a react-app with github pages for hosting and am running into an issue where nothing is showing on the github pages but the information is showing on my localhost with the same homepage.

In my `package.json` I have `"homepage": "Jallard2.github.io/wordleonline"` and in my source code I have `<BrowserRouter basename={"/Jallard2.github.io/wordleonline"}>`. Any help or ideas on why this isn't working is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating homepage to follow formatting
`"homepage": "jallard2.github.io/wordleonline"`